# Does ROS provide any sync mechanism for multiple Kinects?

Tags: kinect, usb, synchronization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Does any one have some ideas on how to sync multiple kinects using ROS? (or any other library)
Or do I have to manually write my own lib for triggering the USBs? (Also, I have a feeling my kinects are on the same USB)
Any references or links are appreciated.
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9584/does-ros-provide-any-sync-mechanism-for-multiple-kinects?/) by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 284 on 2011-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but what you can do via ROS is to use a message_filter::Syncronizer templated on an ApproximateTime sync policy. I do this for the individual topics of one kinect, but you could of course extend it to also subscribe to the topics of the second kinect. My code is as follows:

**Header Stuff:**

```
typedef message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<sensor_msgs::Image,sensor_msgs::Image, sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> MySyncPolicy;
    
message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Image> visual_sub_ ;
message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Image> depth_sub_;
message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> cloud_sub_;
message_filters::Synchronizer<MySyncPolicy> sync_;
```

**Constructor**

```
ClassName::ClassName(ros::NodeHandle nh, 
                     const char* visual_topic, 
                     const char* depth_topic, const char* cloud_topic, 
                     const char* detector_type, const char* extractor_type) 
: visual_sub_ (nh, visual_topic, global_subscriber_queue_size),
  depth_sub_(nh, depth_topic, global_subscriber_queue_size),
  cloud_sub_(nh, cloud_topic, global_subscriber_queue_size),
  sync_(MySyncPolicy(global_subscriber_queue_size),  visual_sub_, depth_sub_, cloud_sub_),
{
  sync_.registerCallback(boost::bind(&ClassName::callback, this, _1, _2, _3));
}
```

I hope this snippet is complete.

For synchrounous triggering of two kinects, I don't think you can achieve that through ROS itself. You would need to dig into the cam driver AFAIK.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) on 2011-03-28**:
Hello Felix, Ya I guess I should look into the cam driver and figure out a way to trigger both USBs at same time. Thank you